# Accessing Matlab Class Properties (aka Constants)

Tags: matlab, class, class-properties

I have some classes that I created a couple of constant properties for. Here is some example code:

```
classdef genericClassName < handle
    properties (Constant)
        Name = 'genericClassName'
        Description = 'description of the class'
    end
...
```

In the main code I create objects by assigning the class handle, which in this case comes from a pre-assigned value delivered from a separate function. It would be like

```
fuctionModel = @genericClassName;
```

and later I'll create other objects and pass the value of *functionModel* to those classes. Up to this point, it all works fine.

The [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html) says that these constant properties are accessed like this:

```
genericClassName.Name
genericClassName.Description
```

I can type that into the command line and it produces the desired result, giving the value of the *Name* or *Description* property - the same values assigned to the constant properties. However, I only have the handle, which is saved in *functionModel* as *@genericClassName*.

**This is my question:** How can I refer to this class and its constant properties when I only have the handle, with its at-sign prepended?

**Update**
Short of a simpler or concise answer, a combination of the answers from @Edric and @CrisLuengo seems to work. For instance:

```
mc=meta.class.fromName(func2str(functionalModel));
result = eval([mc.Name '.Description']);
```

puts the constant with the name *Description* into the variable *result*. This is usable for what I need, and I'll probably just wrap it into a function.

Comment: If you're going to do that, just do `eval([func2str(functionalModel),'.Description'])`. Now you're getting the class description from the name, and only using that description to get the name, which seems rather silly.

Comment: It’s not just about the name, Cris. These are just examples

Comment: What I meant is that if you're not going  to use `mc.PropertyList`, don't get `mc`. `mc.Name` is exactly the string that you put into `mc=meta.class.fromName(...)`. The code you added to your question is very redundant. Also, please post it as an answer, questions should not include an answer. You can accept your own answer if you like.

Comment: Just reread your comment. Yes, the meta.class is not needed. The func2str extracts what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, if you have only a handle to the constructor method, and you wish to avoid constructing an instance (MATLAB allows you to access `Constant` properties from instances), then here's a way you can do it using [`meta.class.fromName`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.fromname.html).

```
fh = @genericClassName;
% Get the metaclass from the constructor
mc = meta.class.fromName(func2str(fh));
% Find the property named 'Name'
idx = strmatch('Name', {mc.PropertyList.Name})
% Get the default (Constant) value
mc.PropertyList(idx).DefaultValue
```

Comment: Thanks, Edric. This is interesting. But the *Name* and *Description* properties are assigned constants within the class definition. Unfortunately, these are the same labels of meta-properties. Of course the meta property *Name* will meet my immediate need. The meta property *Description* is described as "currently not used" in the meta.class class documentation.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. The `meta.class` property "Description" is unrelated to the Constant "Description" property of your class, it just happens to have the same name. You can extract the Constant value of _any_ property using the pattern above by replacing the name in the `strmatch` expression, i.e. `dIdx = strmatch('Description', {mc.PropertyList.Name})`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a class handle. I don’t think there is a way in MATLAB to reference a class other than through its name (either directly in code or as a string). Your code

```
fuctionModel = @genericClassName;
```

stores a handle to the constructor `genericClassName` in the variable `fuctionModel`. With this handle, you can construct objects of your class, but you cannot do anything else. This is not a reference to the class itself.

It is unclear why you have set up your code this way. However, the easiest way to access your constants through this handle is to first create an object of your class:

```
a = fuctionModel();
a.Name
```

[Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651686/7328782) suggests an alternative, also not convenient or pretty.

A third alternative, which I’m not advocating for (this can cause slowdown in your code, and is hard to read and thus maintain) is to store the name of your class as a string, then use `eval` to get your value:

```
fuctionModel = 'genericClassName';
eval([fuctionModel,'.Name']);
```

Comment: I added a link to the Matlab documentation I referred to. (I should have put that in the first place.) It definitely shows that constants defined within a class can be accessed by the classname-dot-propertyname method. My question isn't about accessing constants this way. It's about how to reference the class when I have the name of the class prefixed with an "@" and acheive the same objective - to get the value of the named constant property.

Comment: BTW, the reason I am trying to do this is in line with being Pythonic. I believe this is possible in Python and I'd like to do the same thing here for the benefit of the people who are paying me.

Comment: @rahnema1: probably, yes. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Jim: please read my answer more carefully. You cannot reference a class, I don’t think this is possible at all in MATLAB. What you have is the handle to its constructor. Function handles reference only functions, nothing else.

Comment: @Jim: I've been thinking about your use case. If you want to pass this class reference only to pass a set of constants, then you could instead create a function that returns a struct, something like `function data=foo, data=struct('Name','name','X',10);`. Constants in MATLAB have traditionally been functions, for example `pi` is a function. Since the last few MATLAB releases, you can now do `foo.Name`. And this would be perfectly compatible with your handle: `f=@foo; f().Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Short of a simpler or concise answer, a combination of the answers from @Edric and @CrisLuengo seems to work. For instance:

```
mc=meta.class.fromName(func2str(functionalModel));
result = eval([mc.Name '.Description']);
```

puts the constant with the name Description into the variable result. This works well enough when wrapped in a function.